# regex expression to find out variable type

Tags: sql, regex, types, hive, pattern-matching

I'm using HIVE to import files (which uses sql type syntax) and trying to find out the variable type of my input file which needs to be a regex expression, which may be any of following:

1. Text
2. Long
3. Double
4. Date

So, far I've done:
For Long only: `^(^\\d*$)`
For Double only: `(\\d{0,2}\\.\\d{1,2})`
For Date only: `\\d{2}\/\\d{2}\/\\d{4}`

but the problem is for the Text.

I thought if any of the above criteria doesn't match, then it is a Text and did this:

For Text : `([^(^\\d*$)][^(\\d{2}\/\\d{2}\/\\d{4}])`

but this matches only a part of the Text (i.e if the value contain "updated", the above expression returns only "upd"). I could not understand why it is only the part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just a simple pattern would do like (^[a-zA-Z]+)